# DEFLATE Decoding

Tags: algorithm, compression, zip, deflate

I am currently reading about the DEFLATE method for encoding/decoding data.  I understand that the process is composed of two parts:

i.  Replace duplicate information (within a specified window) with a reference back to the previous identical piece.

ii.  Use Huffman coding to reduce the size of the most commonly occurring symbols.

I have a question with regards to (i).  DEFLATE uses LZ77 which, based on a size window, searches through the information and, if it finds any duplicate information, replaces it with a "pointer".  That makes perfect sense.

However, when decoding using LZ77 how does DEFLATE recognize a pointer?  (Pointers are length-distance pairs; how can you discern if it's a pointer or just a number that was present in the initial data?)

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE#Duplicate_string_elimination

Comment: Some interesting info here: http://zlib.net/feldspar.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended to read the [Deflate RFC 1951 specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt), which is much more precise, and answer such questions.

What you'll see in => 3.2.5. Compressed blocks (length and distance codes)

"the literal and length alphabets are merged into a single alphabet"

which means that, by simply retrieving the next symbol, you immediately know if it is a literal (0..255), or a match length (257..285), or even an end of block (256). In case of a match length, a reference (offset) must be decoded too. Offset are encoded using a separate tree.

Comment: Thanks!  You answered perfectly but I didn't realize about the specification.